# trouble compiling a program using boost regex library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

I tried to compile a boost program which was using boost regex library on my linux box. it has all the required headers and libraries. The program refuses to compile throwing a huge dump of template output. 
I am using the following command to compile the program.

pls advise on how to fix the below.

**g++  regex.cc -I/usr/local/include/boost/  -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_regex  -o regex**

here is the output of the compiler.

```
ravit@ravit-laptop:~$ g++  regex.cc -I/usr/local/include/boost/  -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_regex  -o regex 
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher.hpp:582,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:88,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/regex.hpp:31,
                 from regex.cc:19:
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp: In member function ‘bool boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<BidiIterator, Allocator, traits>::match_assert_backref() [with BidiIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Allocator = std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, traits = boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >]’:
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:180:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<BidiIterator, Allocator, traits>::match_all_states() [with BidiIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Allocator = std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, traits = boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:323:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<BidiIterator, Allocator, traits>::match_prefix() [with BidiIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Allocator = std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, traits = boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:207:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<BidiIterator, Allocator, traits>::match_imp() [with BidiIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Allocator = std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, traits = boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:180:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<BidiIterator, Allocator, traits>::match() [with BidiIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Allocator = std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, traits = boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:50:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::regex_match(BidiIterator, BidiIterator, boost::match_results<Iterator, Allocator>&, const boost::basic_regex<charT, traits>&, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type) [with BidiIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Allocator = std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, charT = char, traits = boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:82:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::regex_match(const std::basic_string<charT, ST, SA>&, boost::match_results<typename std::basic_string<charT, ST, SA>::const_iterator, Allocator>&, const boost::basic_regex<charT, traits>&, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type) [with ST = std::char_traits<char>, SA = std::allocator<char>, Allocator = std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, charT = char, traits = boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >]’
regex.cc:30:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:768: error: request for member ‘back’ in ‘((boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >*)this)->boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::recursion_stack’, which is of non-class type ‘boost::re_detail::recursion_info<boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > [50]’
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:768: error: request for member ‘empty’ in ‘((boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >*)this)->boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::recursion_stack’, which is of non-class type ‘boost::re_detail::recursion_info<boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > [50]’
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:778: error: request for member ‘back’ in ‘((boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >*)this)->boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::recursion_stack’, which is of non-class type ‘boost::re_detail::recursion_info<boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > [50]’
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:778: error: request for member ‘empty’ in ‘((boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >*)this)->boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::recursion_stack’, which is of non-class type ‘boost::re_detail::recursion_info<boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > [50]’
```

here is the piece of code taken from the same boost regex documentation

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void
print_captures(const std::string& regx,
               const std::string& text)
{
   boost::regex e(regx);
   boost::smatch what;
   std::cout << "Expression:  \"" << regx << "\"\n";
   std::cout << "Text:        \"" << text << "\"\n";
   if(boost::regex_match(text, what, e, boost::match_extra))
   {
      unsigned i, j;
      std::cout << "** Match found **\n   Sub-Expressions:\n";
      for(i = 0; i < what.size(); ++i)
         std::cout << "      $" << i << " = \"" << what[i] << "\"\n";
      std::cout << "   Captures:\n";
      for(i = 0; i < what.size(); ++i)
      {
         std::cout << "      $" << i << " = {";
         for(j = 0; j < what.captures(i).size(); ++j)
         {
            if(j)
               std::cout << ", ";
            else
               std::cout << " ";
            std::cout << "\"" << what.captures(i)[j] << "\"";
         }
         std::cout << " }\n";
      }
   }
   else
      std::cout << "** No Match found **\n";
}

int main(int , char* [])
{
   print_captures("(([[:lower:]]+)|([[:upper:]]+))+", "aBBcccDDDDDeeeeeeee");
   print_captures("a(b+|((c)*))+d", "abd");
   print_captures("(.*)bar|(.*)bah", "abcbar");
   print_captures("(.*)bar|(.*)bah", "abcbah");
   print_captures("^(?:(\\w+)|(?>\\W+))*$", "now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party");
   print_captures("^(?>(\\w+)\\W*)*$", "now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party");
   print_captures("^(\\w+)\\W+(?>(\\w+)\\W+)*(\\w+)$", "now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party");
   print_captures("^(\\w+)\\W+(?>(\\w+)\\W+(?:(\\w+)\\W+){0,2})*(\\w+)$", "now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: We cannot help you unless you show us the offending code. Please only post the relevant part, not your whole program.

Comment: here is the piece of code lifted from the same boost documentation it was not written by me.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the regex.cc file, line 30 (regex.cc:30:   instantiated from here) and STARE at it (cross-checking with examples from documentation that DO work) until it becomes clear what you have done wrong. It seems that you're calling back() and empty() on something that does not support these operations. Given [50] at the end of those error messages [which also say non-class type], you've probably forgotten to index an array. (i.e., you have written array.empty() instead of array[i].empty()).

Answer (score 0):

**error: request for member ‘.....’ in '......’** is often caused by either using **.** when you should use **->** or adding () at declaration when you shouldn't, for example:

```
TheClass myTheClass();
```

instead of

```
TheClass myTheClass;
```